# java Time difference outputs negative value and wrong values

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat, duration

I tried the below code.
java Time difference outputs negative value and wrong values when there is hours/date difference between starttime and endtime

```
    Date d3 = null;
    Date d4 = null;
    List<String> activeTimeList = new ArrayList();
    int c = Integer.parseInt(cycle.get("Cycle No:").toString());
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i<c;i++) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US); //("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            String cycleEndTm = cycle.get("End Time"+i+"").toString().trim();
            String cycleStartTm = cycle.get("Start Time"+i+"").toString().trim();

            d3 = format.parse(cycleEndTm);
            d4 = format.parse(cycleStartTm);
            long diff =  d3.getTime() - d4.getTime();
            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            String time1 = diffDays+"."+diffHours+"."+diffMinutes+"."+diffSeconds;

Log :
0.-10.-7.0
```

d4 =02-11-2017 16:47
d3 =02-11-2017 17:27    Diff =  0.-10.-7.0
Not able to get correct time difference? What I am missing here?
Note ** : cycleEndTm -cycleStarttime should be giving positive result. I am reading cycleEndTime and start time from a map. Thats the requirement.

Comment: Verify actual value of variable diff , also try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html class to get time diff

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. From your sample strings I expect a difference of 40 minutes. [I tried running your code online](https://ideone.com/ErRzJI) and it printed `0.0.40.0`, that is, exactly as expected.

Comment: Could your problem lie somewhere else? Could your map contain other values than you expect? Or some third or fourth issue interfere? If you need our help, it’s a very good idea to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes, never `Date`. Convert any `Date` to `java.time.Instant`.

```
Duration                              // Represent a span-of-time as 24-hour days, hours, minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds.
.between(                             // Calculate elapsed time.
    javaUtilDateStart.toInstant() ,   // Convert any `java.util.Date` to `java.time.Instant`. Never use `Date`; it is a terrible class, ditto for `Calendar`. 
    javaUtilDateStop.toInstant()
)                                      // Returns a `Duration` object.
.toString()                            // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

Or call the `to…Part` methods to extract number of days, hours, and so on.

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes ( `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` ) that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

### `Instant`

Apparently you are being handed a `java.util.Date` object. If possible, rewrite that code to use its replacement, the `java.time.Instant` object. Both represent a moment in UTC, but `Instant` has a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds. If not possible, immediately convert the `Date` to an `Instant`. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern class. Same moment in UTC, same point on the timeline.
```

Generate text representing that moment in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

### `Duration`

Calculate elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object. Again, this has a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( instant , now ) ;
```

Generate text representing that elapsed time in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

Or create your string, defining “days” as 24-hour chunks of time without regard for the calendar.

```
long days = d.toDaysPart() ;
int hours = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
int seconds = d.toSecondsPart() ;

String output = days + "." + hours + "." + minutes + "." + seconds ;
```

## Parsing strings

Your Question is not clear about your inputs. If starting with strings, parse. Firstly, if possible, change the source of those strings to use the wisely-defined [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats. If not possible, define a formatting pattern to match the input.

```
String inputStart = "02-10-2018 10.30";

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH.mm" );
```

Parse your input as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) because it lacks any indicator of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldtStart = LocalDateTime.parse( inputStart , f ) ;
```

A `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment, does *not* represent a point on the timeline. This class represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

Assign the zone or offset intended by the source of that string, to give the context needed to determine a moment.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
// Transform the indefinite `LocalDateTime` to a definite moment by assigning the time zone intended by that input string.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ldtStart.atZone( z );
```

Calculate your span of time elapsed.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for showing the good way. As I read the quesiton the start and end datetimes come from strings originally, and are only then parsed into `java.util.Date`s. I know that your suggestion (and mine) would be to avoid that step and parse into a class from *java.time* instead. I believe you can make this point yet clearer.

Comment: @Basil Bourque : How will I parse the string date in this case? I tried as below and getting "Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:"       String s1 = "02-10-2018 10.30";
  String s2 = "02-10-2018 17.35";
  
  Instant instant1 = Instant.parse(s1); 
  Instant instant2 = Instant.parse(s2); and also tried DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
   final ZonedDateTime date1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(s1, formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
   final ZonedDateTime date2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(s2, formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));

Comment: @user10449394 Your Question is not clear about exactly what are your inputs. Are you working with strings or with `java.util.Date` objects? Edit the Question to clarify.

Comment: FYI, parsing strings into date-time values has been covered thousands of times already on Stack Overflow. Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: @user10449394 I added a brief section on parsing input strings. Search Stack Overflow for more discussion and examples.

Comment: @user10449394 Reread my Answer more carefully.  And read the class documentation. `toHoursPart` is very different from `toHours`.

Comment: `Call requires API level 26 (current min is 21): java.util.Date#toInstant` (:

Comment: @Unknown2433 No longer true. The latest Android tooling uses “API desugaring” to bring most of the *java.time* functionality to earlier Android. Alternatively, add the ThreeTenABP library to your project for a back-port of most of *java.time*.

Comment: I have just tested it in latest version of android studio

Comment: @Unknown2433 [A quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+api+desugaring+java.time&t=iphone&ia=web) reveals this Android Studio documentation page, [*Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

This answer does not solve the problem you asked about. In any case I recommend using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The first version here requires *at least Java 9*. Java 6, 7 and 8 follow further down.

```
    Map<String, Object> cycle = Map.of("Cycle No:", 1, 
            "Start Time0", "02-11-2017 16:47",
            "End Time0", "02-11-2017 17:27");

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);
    List<String> activeTimeList = new ArrayList<>();
    int c = Integer.parseInt(cycle.get("Cycle No:").toString());
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            String cycleEndTm = cycle.get("End Time" + i).toString().trim();
            String cycleStartTm = cycle.get("Start Time" + i).toString().trim();

            LocalDateTime d4 = LocalDateTime.parse(cycleStartTm, formatter);
            LocalDateTime d3 = LocalDateTime.parse(cycleEndTm, formatter);

            Duration diff = Duration.between(d4, d3);
            String time1 = String.format(Locale.US, "%d.%d.%d.%d", 
                    diff.toDays(), diff.toHoursPart(), 
                    diff.toMinutesPart(), diff.toSecondsPart());

            activeTimeList.add(time1);
        }
        System.out.println(activeTimeList);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.err.println(dtpe);
    }
```

This prints:

> [0.0.40.0]

The `toXxxPart` methods of the `Duration` class that I use for formatting are not in **Java 8**. So if you are using Java 8, formatting can be done in this way instead:

```
            long days = diff.toDays();
            diff = diff.minusDays(days);
            long hours = diff.toHours();
            diff = diff.minusHours(hours);
            long minutes = diff.toMinutes();
            diff = diff.minusMinutes(minutes);
            long seconds = diff.getSeconds();
            String time1 = String.format(Locale.US, "%d.%d.%d.%d", 
                    days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

The output is the same as before.

If anyone reading along is using **Java 6 or 7**, get [the ThreeTen Backport library](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and the Java 8 code should work there too.

### What went wrong in your code?

The only problem in the code you’ve posted is that you are using the long outdated and poorly designed date and time classes, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone`. There is nothing in your code explaining how you got wrong, negative values, so I suspect that you weren’t parsing the strings you thought you were parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String d4 = "02-11-2017 16:47";
        String d3 = "02-11-2017 17:27";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

        // The given date-times in UTC
        OffsetDateTime odtD4 = LocalDateTime.parse(d4, dtf).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        OffsetDateTime odtD3 = LocalDateTime.parse(d3, dtf).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        // Duration between the date-times in UTC
        Duration duration = Duration.between(odtD4, odtD3);
        System.out.println(duration);    
        
        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format("%02d.%02d.%02d.%02d", duration.toDays(), duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%02d.%02d.%02d.%02d", duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(),
                duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT40M
00.00.40.00
00.00.40.00
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).